# Is there an NS* constant for "many found"?

Tags: objective-c, error-handling, runtime-error, semantics, error-code

I am writing a method that performs an action which will give us an array of `NSError`s. After this, we must handle the returned array:

1. If the array is empty, no error has occurred and we continue as normal
2. If the array has one item, that is the `culprit` so we alert the user, pass it in an `NSError` (with `code: culprit.code`) to a device control API that only takes one error, and prematurely return.
3. If the array has multiple items, we alert the user of all these errors, pass a generic `NSError` (with `code: 0`) to the API, and return.

I want to improve case 3 so that the code (an `NSInteger`) is representative of multiple errors having occurred. **Is there a standard way to represent this in Objective C**, similar to how `NSNotFound` represents that none was found?

Comment: The closest thing that comes to mind is based on the fact that a `NSError` can have a user dictionary attached.  One of the standard keys is `NSUnderlyingErrorKey`, which is sometimes used to describe a cascade of errors.

Comment: @PhillipMills Vaguely brilliant. :) You should give that as an answer.

Comment: @PhillipMills sounds promising! Can you elaborate on that in an answer?